# Batch: remove all white spaces from a text file?

Tags: batch-file

I have text file.

```
 201N001466  AD55JGU0604140     VOLKSWAGEN          GOLF S                      BLACK        
  201N001437  AF14HFY0604140     BMW                 520D SE AUTO             GREY
```

I want to remove all white spaces
and make my output as

```
  201N001466AD55JGU0604140VOLKSWAGENGOLFSBLACK

  201N001437AF14HFY0604140BMW520DSEAUTOGREY
```

My batch file is

```
   @echo off
   setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

   for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (C:\test\Index.txt) do (
  set line=%%A
echo(!line:~1!>>C:\test\Index1.txt
 )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`!line:~1!` removes the first character. What you *want* to do is removing every space, so use string substitution:

```
!line: =!
```

(replace space with nothing)

if there are TABs too, use another `!line:   =!` (that's a TAB, not spaces)

Comment: Is it possible to do this without a for-loop?  Something performant on larger datasets?

Comment: @PabloBoswell not with (pure) batch. a `for` loop is the way to process a file line by line, and there isn't a command to replace something in whole files. 
But dbenham wrote a hybrid JScript/batch script [jrepl.bat](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044), which can do this (and probably a lot faster than a `for` loop)

Comment: I've been reading similar questions for 3 days and this is the only answer that solves the problem. Thank you so much